# Why datepicker returning null?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I have two textboxes the `start_date` and `end_date`. My problem is when I click the `search button` it gives a `null` value. I want to alert and display the value inside the textbox. I think the problem begins is when I clicking the toggle button. I'm using jquery with Vuejs. Can somebody help me with my problem? Here's my jsFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/vL4z071a/

```
toggleView : function() {
    if(this.first_view == true) {
      this.first_view = false;
      this.second_view = true;
    }
    else {
      this.second_view = false;
      this.first_view = true;
    }
    var args = {
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    };
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      $('.datepicker').datetimepicker(args)
      $('.datepicker2').datetimepicker(args)
    });

    this.$nextTick(function() {
      $('.time-picker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
      })
    }); 
},
displayDate : function() {
    alert(this.start_date);
    alert(this.end_date);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datepickers were not existing when you were displaying the `second-view`. I checked if the selectors existed or not and they returned a length of 0. Therefore when selecting the date in the calendar, Vue was not setting the start/end date. I have created a listener on the document itself to listen for `dp.change` and to update the calendars accordingly.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtjLqavc/1/)

```js
$(document).on('dp.change', function(event) {
  if (event.date) {
    var date = event.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    (event.target.className.indexOf('datepicker2') > -1) ? Vue.set(vm, 'end_date', date): Vue.set(vm, 'start_date', date);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is awesome!